# How to display reference values for categorical variables in odds plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression, r-forestplot

I'm running a series of unadjusted logistic regressions with categorical predictor variables, and I want to display the results in an odds plot.

How should I display the reference values for the categorical variables within the odds plot?

Here is some example data:

```
#Creating sample dataframe
df<- structure(list(
'sick'=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
'agecat'=c(23,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,4,4,1,3,1,2,4), 'gender'=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)))
#Factoring vars
df$agecat <- factor(df$agecat, levels=c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("0-19","20-39","40-59","60-79"))
df$gender <- factor(df$gender, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("male","female"))

#Identifying predictor columns
predictors <- c('agecat', 'gender')
cols <- df[predictors]

#Using lapply to generate list of unadjusted logistic regression output
A <- lapply(as.list(cols), function(x) glm(sick ~ x, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit")))

#Creating tibble from list and exponentiating to get ORs
do.call(rbind, lapply(A, broom::tidy, exponentiate=TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)) -> B

#Adding clean var names (quick method - I do this a better way with my actual dataset)
B$varname <- paste0(c("Age","Age","Age","Age","Gender","Gender"))

#Producing basic odds plot
ggplot(B, aes(y = term, x = estimate)) +
  geom_point(shape = 18, size = 3) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), height = 0.4, size=0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, color = "red", linetype = "dashed", cex = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  xlab("Odds Ratio (95% CI)")+
  facet_col(~varname, scales = 'free_y', space='free')
```

In the basic plot I've produced, it displays the intercept estimates and CIs for the reference values.

Should I be excluding these intercepts and leaving the reference values blank within the plot?

I've seen some odds plots where the intercept value is displayed at 1.00, but in my case my exponentiated intercept estimates are not equal to 1.00 - does this indicate a problem?

Comment: My sense is you are misunderstanding what the "intercept" value is in your model, ie, logic(p) = b0 + b1X . The b0 is the coefficient of the intercept (what R returns as `(Intercept)`), *not* your reference value (ie reference of factor X), which will be 1.0 for a ratio measure.

Comment: Ok so looking at my tibble B, where I've exponentiated the results from A, the numbers shown under "estimate" mean two different things depending on the "term" on the left? Where the term is "(Intercept)", the estimate represents the coefficient of the intercept, and where the term is a level of factor X (e.g. "xfemale"), the estimate represents the odds ratio? And the reference value of 1.0 for that odds ratio is not displayed in those exponentiated results but can be assumed?

Comment: The intercept is often disregarded when reporting results from logistic regression. If you are looking for gender, your `B` results say the odds of females having the outcome is 0.444 times that of males. From a reporting standpoint, this has nothing to do with the intercept. I suggest you read up a bit more about logistic regression in general, and specifically to R. [This answer on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63495/268539) may help you get started, but SO is for coding specific questions

Comment: Thanks, I actually read that post on cross validated yesterday and it was helpful! It refers to the raw output of a logistic regression though (as shown in `A`), not the exponentiated results in `B`, which is why I was still confused about the intercept estimates.

Comment: For all intents and purposes the intercepts can be disregarded if you are using logistic regression to examine the association between exposure X and outcome Y. Exponentiating doesn't have anything to do with it, it's just a transformation of the data.

Comment: I guess my main remaining question (which is hopefully coding-related enough), is how to display the output from `B` in an odds plot, where I'm graphing the ORs and their CIs on my x axis and the terms on the y axis? If I'm disregarding the intercept, does that mean I should not display anything at all for the reference value when I graph it? Or should I be replacing the term `(Intercept)` with the reference value and updating the estimate to say 1.0 and displaying that?